# Android Dagger2 - Library usage

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am having problem with new android dagger2 v2.11.
This is just simplified problem of what I am trying to do. I am planing to make shared library that will be used a lot among different applications and put all library di(dagger stuff) logic inside it so I can just hook applications on it.

I will try explain what I have so far.

I have application module named **app** and android library named **dependency-injection. (lib)**
**In app** I have implemented MainActivity with di.
**In lib** I have implemented one activity and one class with di.

I am trying to use these two elements from lib into MainActivity in app using @Inject.

I tried to accomplish it in few ways. 
 1. Implementing all di in lib and all di in app and then just use @Inject in MainActivity.
 2. Make AppComponent and ActivityBuilder implementation in app and extend BaseAppComponent and BaseActivityBuilder from lib in them.
 3. Implement separately di and call lib dagger setup from app application class.

And every time there was some other error. I am not really sure what is the problem so couldn't specified it better. But I have put my simplified project at the bottom so you can take a look or even contribute if it is easier for you to explain.

I have spend last few days trying to understand why is it not working so if you can give me some hint I would be grateful.

Here is my git repo with all attempts: https://github.com/MatejVukosav/Dagger2Composition

Comment: You have a module which is **com.android.library**.  How can a library module have Activities and Application?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your app with Android Studio 2.3.3 after downgrade Gradle version to 2.3.3. Here are changes:

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" 
targetSdkVersion 23 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Also, I replaced *implementation* with *compile*

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Can't accept that as an answer without explanation why it works? Also I think that it is not really happy solution whenever you need to downgrade smth. Especially Gradle version.

Comment: I am not sure what the reason. But I'd suggest you don't use not stable build. You use -beta6 gradle plugin, it's maybe the problem. Moreover, most of the documentation doesn't reflect the changes, so you use features that already may be changed in new version.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trying I have managed to make it run.
But after all there is still some strange feeling about new dagger, and still I am not sure why some stuff didn't work although they should.

In DuckModule I need to add provideActivity() although in single module app, dagger handle it by him self.

```
@Module 
public class DuckModule {

@Provides
DuckActivity provideActivity() {
    return new DuckActivity();   <--
}

@Provides
DuckContract.View providesLibActivity( DuckActivity duckActivity ) {
    return duckActivity;
}
```

}

Second, it looks like lib activity builder is not working at all. It doesn't connect module with activity and provide its insance.

```
@Module
public abstract class PlantActivityBuilder {

@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = DuckModule.class)
abstract DuckActivity bindLibActivity();
```

}

So my lib component get uselles

```
@Component(modules = {
    PlantActivityBuilder.class,
    SharedPrefsModule.class
})
public interface PlantComponent {

}
```

and to make it work I need to put all my modules from lib component into app component:

```
@Component(modules = {
    AndroidInjectionModule.class,
    AppModule.class,
    ActivityBuilder.class,
    SharedPrefsModule.class,  <--
    DuckModule.class  <--
 })
 public interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application( Application application );

    AppComponent build();
}

void inject( App app );

}
```

So now I can @Inject lib objects into my app activity and use them:

```
 @Inject
DuckContract.View view;
@Inject
SharedPrefsInterface prefs;

ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    AndroidInjection.inject( this );
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView( this, R.layout.activity_main );

    ...

    prefs.save();
    view.hashCode();
}
```

If you find some other,faster or cleaner way to make it please share.